# Unable to use custom log handler(java.util.logging) springboot

Tags: spring-boot, logging, java.util.logging

I am facing one logging issue with the springboot application.
Unable to load the custom loghandler(ClassNotFoundException).

Spring boot Uber jar configuration

```
<plugin>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                            <configuration>
                                    <mainClass>test.DigRunner</mainClass>
                                    <layout>JAR</layout>
                            </configuration>
                            <executions>
                                    <execution>
                                            <goals>
                                                    <goal>repackage</goal>
                                            </goals>
                                    </execution>
                            </executions>
                    </plugin>
```

This is the start script for the spring application

exec ${JVM_PATH} -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/temp/logging.properties -jar service.jar

Logging.properties

```
 handlers=utilities.enhancedlogger.handler.file.RollingDayBufferedFileHandler, utilities.enhancedlogger.handler.file.RollingDayFileHandler
level=SEVERE

utilities.enhancedlogger.handler.file.RollingDayBufferedFileHandler.level=INFO
utilities.enhancedlogger.handler.file.RollingDayBufferedFileHandler.buffer.capacity=10000
utilities.enhancedlogger.handler.file.RollingDayBufferedFileHandler.limit=50971520
utilities.enhancedlogger.handler.file.RollingDayBufferedFileHandler.pattern=/temp/dig-debug.log
utilities.enhancedlogger.handler.file.RollingDayBufferedFileHandler.formatter=utilities.enhancedlogger.formatter.Formatter
```

When I Start the spring application it give me error below.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: utilities.enhancedlogger.handler.file.RollingDayBufferedFileHandler
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
```

Tried to manually load the class using below class loader code. But still the same exception

```
Class.forName("utilities.enhancedlogger.handler.file.RollingDayBufferedFileHandler", true, ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
```

Any help is appreciated. Please let me know if any other information is required. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the correct troubleshooting in that you should see if your class is visible to the system class loader.  However, from your question you are referencing 3 different packages:

- `wfplat.utilities.enhancedlogger...`,
- `utilities.enhancedlogger...`
- `com.ge.med.ct.wfplat.utilities.enhancedlogger...`

First step should be to clean that up and make all of your tests and your configuration files point to the fully qualified class name and retest.

At that point if your manual test fails then either the handler is not in the system class path or it wasn't bundled in the jar.  Check the class path to see if the jar containing the handler was on the system class path.  Unpack the jar using your favorite zip tool to see that the binary class file was included and it is the correct package name.

The LogManager will [only load handlers from the system class path](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/38694aa970be73d269cb444ea80ebe7085bd9e90/src/java.logging/share/classes/java/util/logging/LogManager.java#L997). That means you need to make a specific jar for your logging handler and place that on the system class path.  If your handler can't be loaded from the system class path then you have to manually create it and add it to your application logger using code inside of spring boot.

Comment: The packages are all same. It's just the typo. Thanks for pointing out. 
I did jar -tf and found the spring uber jar has the jar which contains the handler class. 

If I import the class in some other, it's able to find. Only problem happens when loading at run time using systemclassloader reflection. I have only one uber jar.

Let me try the last point which you had mentioned.---  "If your handler can't be loaded from the system class path then you have to manually create it and add it to your application logger using code inside of spring boot"

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the jars in the boot classpath which contains the Handlers. The changed script is here and works fine !!!

```
exec ${JVM_PATH} -Xbootclasspath/a:enhancedlogger-extensions-ifc-jar:enhancedlogger-extensions.jar -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/temp/logging.properties -jar service.jar
```